# Welchen Fall verwendet man mit "wert" im Sinne von "worth something"?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-case

Die Beispiele die ich im Wörterbuch gefunden habe, scheinen unterschiedliche Fälle zu verwenden, z.B.

> Es ist nicht der Rede wert.

(Genitiv) oder

> Es ist das Geld wert. Es ist einen Besuch wert.

(Akkusativ) oder

> Es ist lesenswert.

(Genitiv)

Gibt es hier keine einheitliche Regel, die man universal anwenden könnte? Oder sind manche dieser Beispiele einfach falsch?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Die Beispiele sind richtig.

Laut [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/wert) wird *wert* verwendet:

Mit Akkusativ:

> In der Bedeutung »einen bestimmten Wert haben«
>   das ist keinen Heller wert

Mit Genitiv:

> In der Bedeutung »würdig«
>   das ist nicht der Rede wert